# Validate only on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

```
validates :content, presence: true
```

How can I write the above such that it only validates on the `update` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`:on` option](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on):

```
validates :content, presence: true, on: :update
```